# How to use wildcard characters in MySQL Stored Procedures

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

PHP 5.5, MySQL 5.6

Trying to create a stored procedure that implements the use of Wildcards to search a field which has options which are separated by |.

Trying to convert the following embedded query into a stored procedure:

```
$keywords = "Jack";
$sql='select * FROM dealers where searchPhrases LIKE "%|'.$keywords.'|%"'; 
$res=mysql_query($sql);
```

Here is stored procedure Option 1, these are called using PHP PDO, trying to update the project by removing the use of mysql_query from the project.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `getDealerInfo`//
CREATE PROCEDURE `getDealerInfo`(
    IN _search VARCHAR(100)
)
BEGIN
SET @query = CONCAT(
        'select *
        FROM dealers 
        where searchPhrases LIKE "%|'
        ,_search
        ,'|%"');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END//
```

Here is procedure 2:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `getDealerInfo2`//

CREATE PROCEDURE `getDealerInfo2`(
    IN _search VARCHAR(100)
)
BEGIN
select *
FROM dealers 
where searchPhrases LIKE _search;

END//
```

I am testing both out using mysql console and for each case I get 0 results.

```
Call getDealerInfo("Jack");
Call getDealerInfo2("%|Jack|%");
```

Both of these queries in mysql console return 0 records, but if I use the PHP above I get back at least 1 record for the query. How can I fix my stored procedure so that the %, wildcard character, works?

---

**Solution** - Stored Procedure 1 is correct. Thank you @Ravinder. A simple error in judgment. I modified the record in the wrong database.

Comment: 2nd one is not correct but 1st should work. Post some of the table records.

Comment: @Ravinder - Here is a copy of record's searchPhrases  I am looking for:
`|Jack|Harris|Jack Harris|`

Comment: Your current approach has a lot of hidden complications - and why go to a lot trouble when MySQL ships with a very effective text searching grammar built in? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-natural-language.html

Comment: @symcbean that doesn't help resolve the problem when this works using the deprecated mysql_query()

Comment: @mcv: You can use full text searching with mysql_query()

Comment: @symcbean I want to convert this to a stored procedure with wildcards. I want to resolve my issue with using wildcards in a stored procedure.

Comment: Generally, you should be using a REGEX lookup rather than a LIKE.

Comment: anybody could tell me what is the straight line |?  An escaper?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution to get Procedure 2 to work would be to change the line:

```
where searchPhrases LIKE _search;
```

to

```
where searchPhrases LIKE CONCAT('%|',_search,'|%');
```

You would then call the procedure with:

```
Call getDealerInfo("Jack");
```